# ECSlider slight changes, Up to Down Menu Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, menu, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am working with ECSSlider (https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) for iPhone. Need to make some changes in it. I need to show menu by sliding **DOWN** the top menu and then after selecting option slide back **UP** the top menu. I have tried making changes in it but couldn't get the desired results. Changed code is at:https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ujzfsvirktkxz4/ECSlidingViewController-master%20copy.zip
Please guide me if you know the way.

Comment: If you support iOS 7 only, it'll be easier to accomplish this using v2 of `ECSlidingViewController` using the custom layout feature.

Comment: I have amended the current ECSlider Version 1 supporting iOS 5 and above. :)
Let me know if any one need.